Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render with next-auth & socket.io
 const [bidAmount, setBidAmount] = useState<number>(product?.data?.currentPrice); 
 const { data: session } = useSession(); 
 const socket = useClient(); 

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) return;

   const handleConnect = () => {
      console.log('A user Connected...');
   };

   const handleBidPlaced = (data: {productId: string,currentPrice: number}) => {
     console.log('Broadcasted message from server', data);
     if (data.productId === product.data._id) {
       setBidAmount(data.currentPrice);
       toast.success(`New bid placed: $${data.currentPrice}`);
     }
  };

  const handleBidRejected = (data: any) => {
    console.log('Bid rejected message from server', data);
    toast.error(data.message);
  };
    
socket.on('connect', handleConnect);
socket.on('bidPlaced', handleBidPlaced);
socket.on('bidRejected', handleBidRejected);

return () => {
  socket.off('connect', handleConnect);
  socket.off('bidPlaced', handleBidPlaced);
  socket.off('bidRejected', handleBidRejected);
};

}, [socket, product?.data?._id]);

The above code ends up giving the Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
I think its due to early return if the socket connection is not eastablished. and if i remove that part it will end up showing socket is null/undefined how could i solve it??
